# Get distinct count for all column in table using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to get the distinct count for all columns for a table. I want to pass the table as a parameter and then get the distinct count for all columns for that table using pandas.
I tried using below code but it is giving me performance issue on databricks.
Any inputs to improve this code

```
import pyspark.sqlfunctions as F
import pandas as pd

table_name = "Employee"
data = spark.table(table_name)

def unique(data_df):
 data = spark_df.agg(*(F.countDistinct(F.col(i)).alias(i) for i in spark_df.columns)).toPandas()
 return df.rename(index = {0: 'unique count').T

data1 = count_unique(data)
```

Comment: I thought pyspark has `.describe()`?

Comment: Why not simply use `spark_df.nunique(axis=0)`?